# GNU parallel processing

Tags: shell, wireshark, tcpdump, gnu-parallel

I have the following script that I want to run using `GNU parallel`, it is a for loop that needs to be run `n` times. How can I do this using `GNU parallel`?

```
SHARK=tshark

# Create file list
FILELIST=`ls $1`
TEMPDIR=/tmp/foobar
mkdir $TEMPDIR
i=1
for I in $FILELIST; do
    echo "$i $I $2"
    $SHARK -r $I -w $TEMPDIR/~$I-$i -R "$2" &>/dev/null
    i=`echo $i+1|bc`
done
```

Comment: Have you watched the intro videos? https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of doing this, either with sub-shells and sub-processes, see e.g.

- [Running shell script in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547787/running-shell-script-in-parallel)

or by installing neat utilities designed to do this, e.g:

- [|P|P|S|S| - (Distributed) Parallel Processing Shell Script](http://code.google.com/p/ppss/)
- [`GNU Parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

I would try to get it done first with sub-shells, and then try the others if you still need better power.