# Using GNU Parallel etc with PBS queue system to run more than 2 or more MPI codes across multiple nodes as a single job

Tags: mpi, gnu-parallel, pbs

I am trying to run more than 1 MPI codes (eg. 2) in PBS queue system across multiple nodes as a single job.

E.g. For my cluster, 1 node = 12 procs

I need to run 2 codes (abc1.out & abc2.out) as a single job, each code using 24 procs. Hence, I need 4x12 cores for this job. And I need a software which can assign 2x12 to each of the code.

Someone suggested:

[How to run several commands in one PBS job submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281616/how-to-run-several-commands-in-one-pbs-job-submission)

which is:

(cd jobdir1; myexecutable argument1 argument2) &

(cd jobdir2; myexecutable argument1 argument2) &

wait

but it doesn't work. The codes are not distributed among all processes.

Can GNU parallel be used? Becos I read somewhere that it can't work across multiple nodes.

If so, what's the command line for the PBS queue system

If not, is there any software which can do this?

This is similar to my final objective which is similar but much more complicated.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Remote execution with GNU Parallel is covered in chp 8 https://zenodo.org/record/1146014

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://hpcc.umd.edu/hpcc/help/running.html#mpi it seems you need to use `$PBS_NODEFILE`.

Let us assume you have `$PBS_NODEFILE` containing the 4 reserved nodes. You then need a way to split these in 2x2. This will probably do:

```
run_one_set() {
  cat > nodefile.$$
  mpdboot -n 2 -f nodefile.$$
  mpiexec -n 1 YOUR_PROGRAM
  mpdallexit
  rm nodefile.$$
}
export -f run_one_set
cat $PBS_NODEFILE | parallel --pipe -N2 run_one_set
```

(Completely untested).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestions.

Btw, i tried using gnu parallel and so far, it only works for jobs within a single node. After some trial and error, I finally found the solution.

Suppose each node has 12procs. And you need to run 2 jobs, each req 24 procs.

So u can request:

```
#PBS -l select=4:ncpus=12:mpiprocs=12:mem=32gb:ompthreads=1
```

Then

```
sort -u $PBS_NODEFILE > unique-nodelist.txt
sed -n '1,2p' unique-nodelist.txt > host.txt
sed 's/.*/& slots=12/' host.txt > host1.txt

sed -n '3,4p' unique-nodelist.txt > host.txt
sed 's/.*/& slots=12/' host.txt > host2.txt

mv host1.txt 1/
mv host2.txt 2/

(cd 1; ./run_solver.sh) &
(cd 2; ./run_solver.sh) &
wait
```

What the above do is to get the nodes used, remove repetition

separate into 2 nodes each for each job

go to dir 1 and 2 and run the job using run_solver.sh

Inside run_solver.sh for job 1 in dir 1:

```
...
mpirun -n 24 --hostfile host1.txt abc
```

Inside run_solver.sh for job 2 in dir 2:

```
...
mpirun -n 24 --hostfile host2.txt def
```

Note the different host name.